# using BigQuery's APPROX_QUANTILES efficiently

Tags: quantile, google-bigquery

Right now if I want to get the decile of some value I'd do

```
SELECT
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(10)] as p10,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(20)] as p20,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(30)] as p30,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(40)] as p40,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(50)] as p50,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(60)] as p60,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(70)] as p70,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(80)] as p80,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(90)] as p90,
    APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[SAFE_ORDINAL(100)] as p100
FROM table
```

I wanted to make sure this is not 10xing the work for big query, and if there'd be a more compact way to write this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the query and then check the execution plan, you will see that BigQuery only computes the quantiles once, then extracts the various elements of the array in a second step. You don't need to worry about trying to deduplicate the `APPROX_QUANTILES` aggregation yourself.

[image: Sample execution plan]

Comment: Newb question: how do you look at execution plan?